# How to Hide a line in cognos if List does not have any data

Tags: cognos, cognos-bi

How to hide the line in Cognos Analytics report which shows "13. Lab Data" is the list below does not have any rows?
[image: Cognos Report Screenshot]

Comment: Please provide more information.  Is this list within a list, a repeater, a repeater table, or a page set?  Can you develop a similarly-structured report using the GO Sales (query) sample package and post the report spec here?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the Suppression property on the List Container.

[image]